# Dataframe operation when column values are column names of another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

Suppose I have the following two data-frames,

```
data1 = [['abc', 'M', 'T'], ['abc', 'F', 'T'], ['pqr', 'F', 'F'], ['xyz', 'A', 'F']]
data2 = [['abc', 'F', 'T', 'T'], ['xyz', 'T', 'F', 'T']]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, columns = ['name', 'Res', 'flag'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, columns = ['name', 'M', 'F', 'A'])
```

I want to overwrite the flag column value of `df1 (df1['flag'])` based on the values given in `df2` **IF REQUIRED**. For example, there would not be any change for `pqr` in `df1['name']`. I have used `pd.mask` or `replace` function in pandas, but it  is not working. If anybody has any suggestions. My final output will be

```
 data = [['abc', 'M', 'F'], ['abc', 'F', 'T'], ['pqr', 'F', 'F'], ['xyz', 'A', 'T']]
 df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['name', 'Res', 'flag'])
```

```
Out[92]: 
  name Res flag
0  abc   M    F
1  abc   F    T
2  pqr   F    F
3  xyz   A    T
```

Comment: kindly share data not pics. If you can, share the source code of the dataframes

Comment: Please post your attempts and a clear description of the algorithm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

Via `melt()`,`merge()`,`fillna()` and `pop()` method:

```
df2=df2.melt(id_vars='name',var_name='Res',value_name='Flag')
df1=df1.merge(df2,on=['name','Res'],how='left')
df1['Flag']=df1.pop('Flag_y').fillna(df1.pop('Flag_x'))
```

Output of `df1`:

```
    name    Res     Flag
0   abc     M       F
1   abc     F       T
2   pqr     F       F
3   xyz     A       T
```

Comment: @jezrael Thank you so much sir added this in the answer **:)**